# POST to web form using CURL & BASH

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying, without success, to use cURL to post data to the form on this URL:

https://nic.ar/buscarDominio.xhtml

how can i correctly send the request to the server?

I've analysed the post data with chrome (right click, inspect element, network tab), copy as CURL:

```
curl 'https://nic.ar/buscarDominio.xhtml' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=!hh6JmwccX43y6ULiN5rkqiT19gIki8NN0dqDBgaDtQ+kRKM3qulJksgmqjFkb1N+dmFkEA5UteMiyTaLuahx481KkIte4g==; NIC=1007948204.20480.0000; TS2785e3=62b722def584484a84a892fda4181cd30f4798093eac408f542740be60ac0ec5d6bd720d4045274b4076e350; TS2785e3_77=5412_a812844049fdca3a_rsb_0_rs_https%3A%2F%2Fnic.ar%2FbuscarDominio.xhtml_rs_0_rs_0' -H 'Origin: https://nic.ar' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: https://nic.ar/buscarDominio.xhtml' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'busquedaDominioForm2=busquedaDominioForm2&javax.faces.ViewState=3588315592207743676%3A-7314103686046665250&busquedaDominioForm2%3Adominio=example&busquedaDominioForm2%3Aj_idt56=2&busquedaDominioForm2%3AbtnBuscar=Consultar' --compressed
```

But when i run that get empty response from server

Thanks a lot

Comment: Download nic.ar/buscarDominio.xhtml, extract its information to create your post request, send your post request and next time start with *first* step again.

Comment: Right! dont know where to start...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446105/using-curl-to-post-data-to-a-form

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert regarding how to use cURL, in fact I've never used it. However when I [looked it up](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) it stated the proper syntax for it was

```
curl [options] [URL...]
```

In your post it appears you've got the URL first, and your options after. Maybe it is failing to post data because the URL is first and thus the curl command sees no options to pass to it.